RAG Conditional Formatting based on String from Dax Measure in Vega Lite
I have a bar chart created in Deneb/Vega-Lite that I want to fill either red, amber or green depending on a DAX measure that result that outputs a string of either Red, Amber or Green based on a calculation.
I can make it so the bar fills one of two colors based using datum.mymeasure but I cannot work out how to have multiple options.
Does anybody know how to do this?
I've tried condition or param but I cannot work out the syntax of it.

Please supply a sample spec or sample .pbix for us to help.
